# SharePoint 2010 SSL certificate with no FQDN

Tags: ssl

We're migrating our customer's MOSS2007 site to SharePoint 2010 (on new hardware). The client wishes to continue using the same URL to make the upgrade as transparent as possible to the end users. However, we need to enable SSL.

The problem is getting SSL to work with their current URL as it's a single level URL, something like -- 'http://ourwebserver/'

I need to register a public cert with Thawte, but I'm told it's only possible to register an FQDN URL with Thawte.

Is it possible to get this working? The only thing I can think of in my limited knowledge of SharePoint is to register the companies FQDN on the cert, i.e. 'http://ourwebserver.abc.efg.sg' and then create some AAM in SharePoint so that that the users can still access via 'http://ourwebserver' securely.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Adrian

Answer (score 1):

Can't you get an internal cert made for ourwebserver and use that?

You can also use redirects so that the old url's still work but will redirect to the correct new url.  I've done this before using an httpmodule.  I also redirected them to a page which says they are using an "old link" and show them the new link and have a javascript thing that automatically redirects them in 30 seconds.  This way people are informed and quickly move to the new url structure.

Comment: Thanks Steve. Unfortunately the external CA is a fixed requirement, I'm not sure of the politics behind it but I imagine it was a policy to save work, ironically, it's making life difficult. As for the redirect: That's a good idea, unfortunately, the user want's a 'seamless' experience. It's more to do with change management as it's a big government agency and there will be another URL change in a later phase of the project -- so basically they want to minimize disruption for this phase. For now I'm recommending they wait until a later phase to implement SSL.